# How to simplify this: "can include, but not limited to"

Tags: phrases

I am writing a list of props and found myself writing

> ...including, but not limited to...

(and here in context):

> - Options for Scary Creatures (can include, but not limited to);
>
>   - Mummy
>   - Vampire
>   - Frankenstein's Creature
>   - Goblin
>   - C'thulu

My question is this: Is there a nicer way to write this phrase. I want to say, "here is a list of scary creatures that you can include, but if you want to use something else, then go for it", but in a nicer way.

Comment: I think you mean "Frankenstein's Monster." /pedant

Comment: By the way, isn't there an *is* missing, as in "can include, but is not limited to"?

Comment: Note that "including" is very different from "can include". The former guarantees inclusion, the latter specifies items that might be, but are not necessarily included.

Comment: may i suggest C'thulu as a monster?

Comment: Why "options… *can* include"? The options *do* include these, don't they? Is there some later date where the list of options will be decided, and it is not known whether these will then be included among options or not?

Comment: @PyroTyger: Actually, Frankenstein *was* the monster, and his creature the man :-). (Though the creature certainly is scarier than Frankenstein, and so is more appropriate for this list.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more concise version would be:

Possible Scary Creatures:

- Mummy
- Vampire
- Frankenstein's Monster
- Goblin
- Margaret Thatcher

Comment: Though this could imply these are the *only* possible choices, which is what OP was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

A full sentence may better introduce this list:

> - Options for Scary Creatures would include, for instance:
>
>   - Mummy
>   - Vampire
>   - Frankenstein
>   - Goblin

That would make the possibility of using other terms implicit.

Comment: Even "would" is unnecessary, IMHO. All of these *are* options already, not merely conditionally on something happening in future.

Comment: I don't think we can say that 'would' is unnecessary without knowing the full context.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

- Options for Scary Creatures, e.g.:

  - Mummy
  - Vampire
  - Frankenstein's Monster
  - Goblin